# Windows Server 2008R2, Running dcpromo.exe produces the error to run adprep /forestprep

Tags: windows-server-2008

Windows Server 2008R2

I have Windows Server SP2 ( 32-bit) that was used to create the forest and DC. I am adding a new server with Windows Server 2008R2.
Running dcpromo.exe on the R2 server and trying to add a new DC to the existing forest produces the error to run adprep /forestprep.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. YOu reated the domain with an older version of the server and the forest is not ready for the new one. Just do what it says. And - read the documentation to how domains work somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I guess he means 2008 SP2 -> 2008 R2, in which case a schema update would be required.